# JavaScript error top is undefined

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a few pages that load primarily in an iframe. But sometimes they load outside of it

But top is undefined when opened outside it. I know I can check if top is defined then use self if not defined. Is there a better way?

Comment: `top = top || self; top.location.href=…`

Comment: all browsers support `window.top` but maybe not `top` so either use above comment ,or use window.top

Comment: I know it's unlikely, but is `top` being overridden somewhere else with a `var top;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `window.top` will *always* be defined (at least in FF and Chrome) and refer to `window` itself if the page is loaded as top document, so this *should* not be an issue.
OTOH, `window.top` is not part of any standard, so browsers might implement it differently (yes, I'm looking at you, IE). More info: [MDN - `window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top).

In case you have to test, you can make it compact:

```
(window.top || window.self).location.href = ...;
```

Comment: but top===window.top how come it be undefined ?? by default window.top refer to window.self if ther is no other window is suppose

Answer (score 1):

did you try like:

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
// variable is undefined
}
```